# How to handle exceptions due to missing attributes in current session (in Symfony2)

Tags: exception, symfony, controller

I was wondering if there are some specific exceptions for handling session missing attributes (in the controller), though i don't feel is right to couple a multi-step use case to the business layer (e.g. surveys)

Comment: Can you be more precise? For example by showing an algorithm or some code ?

Comment: algorithm? i'm asking about an exception with a specific semantic

    throw new AnExceptionWithTheRightMeaningException('do you know what i mean, right?');